# Prove the set is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $*$ be defined on the set of positive rational numbers by $a*b=\frac{ab}{2}$.

So I was proving that this set is a group and the last component I needed to prove was the existence of the inverse.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $a*b=2 \Rightarrow \frac{ab}{2}=2 \Rightarrow b=\frac{4}{a}.$

Comment: alright I understand how you got to this step, but next should I plug it into the equation and solve for a? I'm a little confused what my final step should look like..

Comment: I plugged the value for b in and it all checks out. Is that the complete proof?

Comment: Yes! Given $a,$ we want to find $b$ such that $a*b=2=b*a.$ (Here $2$ is the identity element.) The above equation shows that for $b=4/a$ we have this property. So the inverse of $a$ is $4/a.$ (Note that $4/a$ is also a positive rational.)

Answer (score 1):

First find the identity element of the group from $a*e=a$. Then for the inverse of $a$ find $x$  from the equation $a*x=e$.